# django app randomly calling a sympy test

Tags: django

I've been having a problem on my server where things would suddenly lock up, so i found some niffy code on SO and used it when the server locked up again to print the stack traces of all the server threads.

Most of the threads were doing things they were supposed to be, but this one seemed really odd. It appears to be calling a sympy test. I can't understand how it went from a template tag to sympy at all.

```
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 248, in __call__
  response = self.get_response(request)
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in get_response
  response = middleware_method(request)
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/protected/middleware.py", line 16, in         process_request
  login_url = reverse('protected-login')
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 351, in reverse
  *args, **kwargs)))
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 272, in reverse
  possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 194, in _get_reverse_dict
  self._populate()
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 162, in _populate
  for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 244, in _get_url_patterns
  patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 239, in _get_urlconf_module
  self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
  __import__(name)
File: "/var/www/site/urls.py", line 12, in <module>
  from sitelib.urls import initialize_urls
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/utils/urls.py", line 11, in <module>
  admin.autodiscover()
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/utils/default_settings.py", line 178, in init_defaults
  logging.error("Error setting up logging: %s" % ex)
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/template/__init__.py", line 1049, in add_to_builtins
  builtins.append(import_library(module))
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/template/__init__.py", line 997, in import_library
  return mod.register
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/django/utils/importlib.py", line 36, in import_module
  return sys.modules[name]
File: "/opt/django-live1.0/misc/templatetags/misc_tags.py", line 427, in <module>
  @make_tag
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
  evalf._create_evalf_table()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <mod
ule>
  exec '%s = _cls()' % (_n)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/core/basic.py", line 2505, in <modu
le>
  from numbers import Rational, Integer
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/mpmath/__init__.py", line 385, in <
module>
  doctests()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/mpmath/ctx_fp.py", line 12, in <mod
ule>
  class FPContext(StandardBaseContext):
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/mpmath/ctx_base.py", line 31, in <m
odule>
  VisualizationMethods):
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/mpmath/identification.py", line 840
, in <module>
  doctest.testmod()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/mpmath/libmp/__init__.py", line 63,
 in <module>
  from backend import (gmpy, sage, BACKEND, STRICT, MPZ, MPZ_TYPE,
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/mpmath/libmp/libmpf.py", line 1317,
 in <module>
  pass
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/mpmath/libmp/libintmath.py", line 4
25, in <module>
  def eulernum(m, _cache={0:MPZ_ONE}):
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sympy-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/sympy/mpmath/libmp/libintmath.py", line 6
5, in python_trailing
  return t
```

@make_tag is just a snippet that turns a function into a template tag

Anyone know how this could happen?

Comment: Maybe try clearing your .pyc files?

Comment: Or maybe somehow the threads are polluting each other (stderr is getting mixed up or something).  Does your project actually use sympy?  Is this reproducible?

Comment: Yes, i found that it was for the "fraction" function. It was in the same file, but not the same line as the trace. I found there was another module that provided a similar "fraction" function, so that's what i used to fix this. I haven't seen the issue again and the memory leak on our server seems to have gone away.